# "time aware" vs "temporal aware"

Tags: word-choice

What is the best way to indicate that a certain model is aware of time or exploits the time dimension?

Would you call it "a time aware model" or "a temporal aware model".
Or is it better to directly call it "a time model" or "a temporal model"?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Because "aware" is an adjective, you need to modify it with either a noun or an adverb, not an adjective: so "time aware" or "temporally aware" are ok, but not "temporal aware". Not sure I can answer the rest of the question.

Comment: 'Temporal' is 'correct' but is probably not a suitable choice as the broadest  'involving time in some way' meaning is usually (and so expected to be) in some way narrowed in usage. A 'temporal model' would be open to various interpretations.  // The metaphorical/personificational use of 'aware' here is another complicating factor. I can't go beyond say 'This model, which unlike some addresses time as a factor, ...'. 'The _time factor_' is sadly already a fixed phrase perhaps better avoided here.

Comment: There are lots of references in Google Books to [***temporally-aware model***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22temporally+aware+model%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03CLzC6z04uFq-IBnhqqLB2Yneq3A:1612269350982&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC1cmvm8vuAhUSTxUIHWKGCuIQpwUIJg&biw=1536&bih=732&dpr=1.25), but not a single one for ***temporal aware model***. There are also lots of references to [***temporally sensitive model.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22temporally+sensitive+model%22)

Comment: I see also the temporal-aware spelling in some titles of academic publications.
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=temporal+aware+model

Comment: @FumbleFingers Temporally-aware looks like the right option, Thank you for the suggestion.